# How to Get VNET (VirtualNetwork) Information connected to Specific Virtual Machine in Azure using Azure-SDK for Python

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-sdk-python

I want to get information about Virtual Machine from Azure Using Azure-SDK for Python .
I'm able to get information of VM by providing resource-group and
virtual-machine name in computeClient

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
    credentials,
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID
)
compute_client.virtual_machines.get(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME, expand='instanceView')
```

But above code doesn't give me Vnet information

Can someone guide me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, all you can get from the ComputeManagementClient SDK are network interfaces fo the VM, no such as Vnet, subnet. It's the configuration of the network interfaces.

So what you need to do is to get the information of the network interface, and then it will show you the config of the Nic, it contains the subnet which the Nic in.

I assume you only know the VM info, then you can get the Vnet info like this:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient


subscription_Id = "xxxxxxxxx"
tenant_Id = "xxxxxxxxx"
client_Id = "xxxxxxxxx"
secret = "xxxxxxxxx"

credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id=client_Id,
        secret=secret,
        tenant=tenant_Id
        )

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, subscription_Id)
group_name = 'xxxxxxxxx'
vm_name = 'xxxxxxxxx'
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get(group_name, vm_name)
nic_name = vm.network_profile.network_interfaces[0].id.split('/')[-1]
nic_group = vm.network_profile.network_interfaces[0].id.split('/')[-5]

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_Id)
nic = network_client.network_interfaces.get(nic_group, nic_name)
vnet_name = nic.ip_configurations[0].subnet.id.split('/')[-3]
vnet_group = nic.ip_configurations[0].subnet.id.split('/')[-7]

vnet = network_client.virtual_networks.get(vnet_group, vnet_name)
```

All the above code, I assume the VM only has one Nic, and Nic only has one configuration. If the VM has multiple Nics and each Nic has multiple configs. You can get them one by one inside a for each loop. Finally, you got the information about the Vnet that you want.

Comment: Work like charm ..thanks ...Adding to above i added following for loop to get subnets :`for subnet in vnet.subnets:
        print("Subnet_Name = ", subnet.name)`

Comment: @VishalKothawade That's great. And if it works for you, please accept it as the answer.